# How was I able to login without a password and without authorized_keys?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, google-compute-engine

I started with a box at Google Compute Engine (Google's cloud service) with an account named xyz and an ephemeral IP address.

Let's pretend the ephemeral IP address was 2.3.4.5.

Before I started the process below, I was able to login to xyz@2.3.4.5 with a password.

I then attached a static IP address. Let's pretend the static IP address was 1.2.3.4.

I then typed

```
my@localbox:~$ ssh-copy-id xyz@1.2.3.4
```

The command seem to hang, so I killed the terminal.

I then did a simple

```
my@localbox:~$ ssh xyz@1.2.3.4
```

Which succeeded without prompting me for a password.

I assumed that my key had made it into my authorized_keys, so I did

```
xyz@cloudbox:~$ ls -al
```

To my surprise, .ssh contained only a known_hosts file, not an authorized_keys file.

Additionally, the command

```
my@localbox:~$ ssh-copy-id xyz@1.2.3.4
```

still hangs when I try it, so it wasn't just a random fluke.

How am I able to login to this account without a password if there's no .ssh/authorized_keys file? Is it related to the cause of ssh-copy-id hanging?

Comment: can you paste the servers sshd.conf?

Comment: @Gotschi It's almost 100 lines...Are there specific values that are relevant?

Comment: checking my ssh, the authorized_keys file should be in the `.ssh` subdirectory  So since you logged into 1.2.3.4/cloudbox, have a look for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` there, or even authorized_keys2  i've heard of that one too. But look in the `.ssh` subdirectory list files there

Comment: I don't know about ssh-copy-id hanging.. here i'm v unsure but I wonder if it uses a password and that isn't working.. or if there's a verbose mode for it like -v or -vvv or if you try not managing to get the public key and it goes to password so you can check if it manages to log in via password.. maybe you could try starting again with configuring it, so first get password working then keys.

Comment: Oh actually I figured it out a while after posting this question. It was a SSH control master session that was running in the background. ssh-copy-id hanging with control master is a known bug

Comment: @user939259 please consider to add your most recent update to the answer section and accept it to close this question off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a SSH control master session that was running in the background. ssh-copy-id hanging with control master is a known bug.